# Android Standard Bottom Sheet with animated toolbar when sheet expanded

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, bottom-sheet

I have a fragment, within that fragment I want to display a standard bottom sheet. When the sheet is expanded Id like to display a toolbar at the top of the sheet, with close/collapse button, something like presented on https://material.io/components/sheets-bottom#behavior under Behaviour -> Visibility -> FullScreen

To my surprise Im struggling to achieve similar effect - tried applying different scroll flags (app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed") however Im getting opposite results - toolbar is visible when sheet is half extended and disappars when I scroll the sheet to the top.